# Why property inside initWithFrame is null on Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I'm trying to develop a react-native module, and I don't know how Objective-C works, so I'm going by intuition and attempts.

So, I know that here is where my banner it's load and shown to the app. This is working.

**BannerView.m**

```
@implementation BannerView

...

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {        
            [self.bannerUnit setAutoRefreshMillisWithTime:35000];
            self.dfpView = [[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle];
            ...
            self.dfpView.adUnitID = @"/6499/example/banner";
            ...
            [self addSubview:self.dfpView];
        }
        return self;
    }
```

And I have this method where is the bridge RN-Objective-C

```
- (void)loadBanner
{
   ...
}
```

At **loadBanner**, I'm able to get my properties like

```
<Banner adUnitID={'123'} // inside RN

_adUnitID // inside Objective-C
```

Problem now, is that inside **initWithFrame**, _adUnitID is always null. I tried _adUnitID, self._adUnitID, self.adUnitID. But still the same.

```
NSLog(@"adUnitID %@", _adUnitID); // always null
```

[UPDATE]

This is where I define *adUnitID*

**BannerViewManager.m**

```
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

...

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(adUnitID, NSString)
```

**BannerView.h**

```
@interface BannerView : RCTView <GADBannerViewDelegate>

...

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *adUnitID;
```

So, what could I be doing wrong? Is it possible to be done?

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you set `_adUnitID` or `self.adUnitID`. Do you mean `self.dfpView.adUnitID`? `self.dfpView` is a different object than `self`.

Comment: @RobNapier, inside BannerViewManager.m and BannerView.h, check the update.

Comment: Right, but where do you *set* it?